# How to make items in a list clickable and lead to a new page with a specific format In android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm trying to make a page that has a list view in android, and then when you click on one of the items in the list, it should lead to a  new activity, with a specific format.

Basically, it's a grades centre page, with a list of your courses, when you click on a course it should open to a course page.

I have created a Grades centre activity, a single course page activity and their respective classes.

Right now the 2 pages exist but they aren't linked to each other, This is actually a huge file with many other pages etc, but I just posted the part I need help with but if necessary I can post the others as well. I want the elements in the list to be clickable - and then lead to the course page that the user clicked on, like one of the courses is Biol 116 then the list should take you to the biol 116 course page. Thanks in advance for all the help! :)

GradeCentre xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_grades_centre"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gregmallan.yuboard.GradesCentre"><![CDATA[

android:clickable="true">

]]>

<TextView
    android:text="Current Overall Grade:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/CourseGradeList"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="85.67"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/Overall"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/CourseGradeList"
    android:layout_marginStart="17dp" />
```

GradeCentre java file:

```
public class GradesCentre extends AppCompatActivity {

   double OverallAvg;
    ArrayList<Course> AllCourses;
    ArrayAdapter<Course> AdapterCourse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grades_centre);

        AllCourses = new ArrayList<>();

        AllCourses.add(new Course("Cosc 111"));
        AllCourses.add(new Course("Biol 116"));
        AllCourses.add(new Course("Anth 100"));

        AllCourses.get(0).setCourseGrade(95);
        AllCourses.get(1).setCourseGrade(78);
        AllCourses.get(2).setCourseGrade(84);

        OverallAvg = calcOverallGrade(AllCourses);

        AdapterCourse = new ArrayAdapter<Course>(this ,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , AllCourses);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CourseGradeList);
        listView.setAdapter(AdapterCourse);

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {

    }

    public double calcOverallGrade(ArrayList<Course> Anything){
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Anything.size();i++ ){
            sum = Anything.get(i).getCourseGrade() + sum;
        }
        OverallAvg = sum/(Anything.size());
        return OverallAvg;
    }

}
```

Single Course Page xml:

```
<TextView
    android:text="_________________________________________________"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SingleCourseGrade"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="_________________________________________________"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SingleCourseGrade"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="ex. Course 1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/CourseName"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<TextView
    android:text="Current Overall Grade: "
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CourseName"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_width="200dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Add/Manage Components"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/AddManage"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/SingleCourseGradeList"
    android:layout_above="@+id/AddManage"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/AddManage"
    android:layout_height="315dp"
    android:layout_width="280dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="%%%"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/SingleCourseGrade"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:text="_________________________________________________"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="Individual Components and Grades:"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_above="@+id/SingleCourseGradeList"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/SingleCourseGradeList" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Single course page java file:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.gregmallan.yuboard.SchoolRelatedClasses.CourseComponent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SingleCoursePage extends AppCompatActivity{

ArrayAdapter<CourseComponent> adapter;

Button Components;
Button CompDetail;

double CourseGrade;

ArrayList<CourseComponent> AllComponents;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_course_page);
//this is just added until we get real data
    AllComponents = new ArrayList<CourseComponent>();

    CourseComponent x = new CourseComponent("Dummy", 20);
    AllComponents.add(x);

    CourseComponent x2 = new CourseComponent("Dummy2", 40);
    AllComponents.add(x2);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CourseComponent>(this ,       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , AllComponents);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SingleCourseGradeList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Components = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddManage);
    Components.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Inform the user the button has been clicked
            openCourseComponents(v);
        }
    });

}

public void openCourseComponents(View view){
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, IndividualCourseCentre.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

//public void openComponentBreakdown(View view){
  //  Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, IndividualCourseCentre.class);
   // startActivity(intent2);
//}


public double calcCourseGrade(ArrayList<CourseComponent> x){

    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size();i++){
        sum = x.get(i).getTotalComponentGrade();
    }
    CourseGrade = sum/(x.size());
    return CourseGrade;

    //TO-DO
    //when this method is called changed the text to the CourseGrade
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                String selectedFromList =(String) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(GradesCentre.this, Cosc111Activity.class);
                if(selectedFromList.equals("Cosc 111")){
                    //Set object here
                    intent.putExtra("Course_Details", obj);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               else if(selectedFromList.equals("Biol 116")){
                    //Set object here
                    intent.putExtra("Course_Details", obj);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

               //Do as above for rest of the list items
            }
        });
```

Get the object in SingleCourseActivity like this:

```
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Course_Details");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response! That helps but the problem is I don't have  Cosc111 activity class -- the items in the list change they are not only the default values, like a user is allowed to add a course. Is there a way to do that? Or do I have to have an activity for every course? There are about 1000 courses total. Also is the following code supposed to be in my Grade Centre on create? Thanks again ! :)

Comment: Yes, It is ridiculous to use 1000 activities for 1000 courses. Instead you can have single activity. You can pass values of corresponding course in an object and pass it to the single activity. You can set values of object wherever you want. Check my updated answer please.